# Fancy header with \thechapter still shows "Chapter" after \appendix. Should show "Appendix"

Tags: header-footer

I have chapters and appendices. I am not using `\part`. My header is defined as

```
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textsf{\footnotesize \thechapter--\thepage}}
```

After I move from chapters to appendices (after `\appendix`), the appendix headings are ok, but the header says "Chapter A: blah" rather than "Appendix A: blah".

Comment: Please, provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Sorry, what's a MWE?

Comment: It stands for a minimal working example. The link explains it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My configuration is fairly complex, but maybe this will suffice.Having trouble editing (first time contributing to this website), more to come

Comment: \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textsf{\footnotesize \thechapter--\thepage}}

Comment: @AnneH. `\thechapter` is usually defined just to print the chapter (or appendix) number, but not the word `Chapter`. Either your definition of `\thechapter` is weird or something different does not match your request

Comment: That's in init.tex; in my file to compile I input that then I input some chapters, then do \appendix then input some appendices. Is this enough to go on? I haven't figured out how to add code here -- the add comment is pretty restrictive.

Comment: I have   \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%      
\markboth{Chapter \thechapter:\ #1}{}}  
\fancyhead{}  
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textsf{\footnotesize \thechapter--\thepage}}  
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsf{\footnotesize \leftmark}}

Comment: I can't find where \thechapter is actually defined.

Comment: Fixed it!  Added in two commands after \appendix to redefine:
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{     
\markboth{Appendix \thechapter:\ #1}{}}

Comment: the command `\@chapapp` expand to chapter first and to appendix after the use `\appendix`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.

the command `\@chapapp` expand to chapter first and to appendix after the use `\appendix` we can use it here
`\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\@chapapp{} \thechapter:\ #1}{}}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{% 
\markboth{\@chapapp{} \thechapter:\ #1}{}} 
\fancyhead{} 
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\textsf{\footnotesize \thechapter--\thepage}} 
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsf{\footnotesize \leftmark}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\appendix 
\blinddocument 
\end{document}
```